# RECURSAO EM C - CONTAR NUMEROS PARES DE UM VETOR

Tags: c, array, recursão

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 6

int verificaPar (int v[], int n, int qtd, int indice); // protótipo

int main()
{
    int vetor[N] = {13, 6, 8, 3, 4, 9};    // vetor igual do exercicio
    int resultado ; // ja tentei inicializar como 0 para ver se nao tem lixo e n adiantou

    resultado = verificaPar(vetor, N, 0, 0); // verificando o retorno(quantidade)

    if(resultado > 0)
    {

        printf("Quantidade de numeros pares:   %d\n", resultado);
    }// printando a quantidade
    else
    {
        printf("Nao ha numeros pares\n");
    }
    return 0;

}

int verificaPar(int v[], int n, int qtd, int indice)
{

    if(v[indice]%2 == 0) //verificação pra ver se o numero daquela posicao é par.
    {
        qtd++;
    }
    if( v[indice] >= n-1)  // verifica se o indice chegou ao final do total de numeros do vetor.(n-1 pq a ultima posicao tem n-1 d indice)
    {
        verificaPar(v,n,qtd, indice+1);
    }

    else
    {
        return qtd; // se sim, devolve a quantidade acumulada de numeros pares.
    }


}
```

NAO SEI O QUE PODE ESTAR ERRADO, MAS ELE NAO TA CONTANDO CERTO.

Comment: Nesta condição:  if( v[indice] >= n-1) não deveria encerrar e retornar a quantidade?

Comment: verdade, troquei as linhas. obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Essa função faz o trabalho e é bem mais simples (além de fazer mais sentido com recursão), creio:

```
int contaPar(int *v, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0; // Lista vazia, nao tem numeros, muito menos pares!

    return contaPar(v + 1, n - 1) + 1 - v[0] % 2; // Soma 1 se o atual for par e chama a funcao pro vetor deslocado de uma posição
}
```

Onde `v` é o vetor e `n` é o número de elementos dele.

Para um vetor `v`, podemos definir recursivamente o número de pares nele como o número de pares no vetor a partir da posição 1 somado com k, onde k é 1 se o primeiro for par e 0 se não.

Veja que `1 - x % 2` satisfaz o "1 se x for par, 0 se não".

`v + 1` é justamente o vetor a partir da posição 1, e subtraímos 1 no `n` para a próxima iteração porque esse vetor tem um elemento a menos.